# How to transfer data from DB1 to DB2 (different network/server)

Tags: php, database

I want to set up a website with a form in it. The form will transfer the data to the `DB`, but I think it is not safe to let the personal data in the DB which is external reachable.
So I thought I should transfer the data via `PHP` from the `DB1`(server1 - external reachable) to `DB2`(server2 - only internal reachable).

> The following picture should help to know what I am searching for.

[image: diagram]

Is there any names/methods to google for?

Comment: Maybe it should be 2 DB, but the data should be transfer to Server 2 to DB 2 (image)

Answer (score -1):

From php you just have to create a new connection for DB2.

```
<?php
   $servername = "localhost";
   $username = "database1";
   $password = "xxxxxxxx";
   $dbname = "database1";


   $servername2 = "localhost";
   $username2 = "database2";
   $password2 = "xxxxxxxx";
   $dbname2 = "database2";

   // Create connection
   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
   $conn2 = new mysqli($servername2, $username2, $password2, $dbname2);

   // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   }
   if ($conn2->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn2->connect_error);
   }

   //escape variables for security
   $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['fname']);
   $lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lname']);

   $sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (fname,lname) 
   VALUES ('$fname','$lname')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     echo "Successfully Saved";

    } else {
      echo "Error: Go back and Try Again ! " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    if ($conn2->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     echo "Successfully Saved";

    } else {
      echo "Error: Go back and Try Again ! " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn2->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
    $conn2->close();

   ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So there isn't any special methods? You just need to connect to the DB even if the DB is on another server which is only for the internal network?

Comment: I don't think any special method is there. Yes just create a connection and use it even it's internal or external.